# Defining Consumer Tag for RabbitMQ using Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

Is it possible to define the consumer tag for a rabbitmq binding using spring cloud stream?

For example, I am binding to rabbitmq and am seeing the following for my consumer tag in the admin console: amq.ctag-qeGdyc32v1BS4LkYHi39aw.

I don't see any obvious settings to handle this directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming in the next release 2.1

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/commit/e104de2204b2a247e30bde3f74cbe95ba12dac91

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Gary!